# How can I query data from a source game server?

Tags: source-engine

After reviewing things like [Game Tracker](http://gametracker.com), [xqf](http://www.linuxgames.com/xqf/index.shtml), and [HLSW](http://www.hlsw.org/) I've come to the bold conclusion that most source games are publicly queryable for basic information like map, player count, player list, etc. Is there some standard for this? I ultimately want to create my own script to poll this information I just can't find any documentation on how it's retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to do some house advertising here, but [Steam Condenser](http://koraktor.de/steam-condenser) is probably the way to go if you want to do this programmatically in either Ruby, Java or PHP.
It provides all you need to query Source and GoldSrc game servers, the master servers and the Steam Community (like profile, inventories and achievements).

Comment: From the link in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30734/how-can-i-query-data-from-a-source-game-server/30736#30736) I ended up at the Steam Condenser which is what I'm using now.

Comment: Thanks for using my library. Feel free to contact me if you need further help.

Answer (score 4):

Valve's wiki has an article on the topic.  Too much to quote, but the link should be stable.

http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Comment: This is exactly the documentation I was looking for in order to get started - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that most Source games still use Srcds for servers. In which case maybe this tutorial will be of help to you:

http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/5239